# Split a tree in a forset using jgrapht

Tags: java, tree, jgrapht

I have a tree represented with the library jgrapht, there are variuous type of nodes I need to cut any subtree starting from a particulare node type.

[image: graph example]

As you can see in this example, this tree represent a source code of a Java class. I need to create multiple jgrapht objects by splitting the main tree starting for each "Entry" node type. In total I should get 7 tree from this big one. The structure I use is a `DirectedPseudograph`.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by " I need to cut any subtree starting from a particulare node type."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not 100% clear about what you want, it seems there are various solution approaches.

1. Starting from every outgoing neighbor of the root node, you could run a depth first search and record the nodes returned. The nodes reachable by the DFS algorithm belong to the same subtree. For this you can use the [DepthFirstIterator](https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht/blob/master/jgrapht-core/src/main/java/org/jgrapht/traverse/DepthFirstIterator.java)
2. You could create a subgraph without the root node, for instance by using the [AsSubgraph](https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht/blob/master/jgrapht-core/src/main/java/org/jgrapht/graph/AsSubgraph.java) class. You can then invoke the [ConnectivityInspector](https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht/blob/master/jgrapht-core/src/main/java/org/jgrapht/alg/connectivity/ConnectivityInspector.java) on the resulting induced subgraph. Since every subtree is a disconnected graph component, the connectivity inspector will be able to find each of these components.

Btw, unless you need the capabilities of a Pseudograph, for performance it would be better to use the SimpleDirectedGraph. Obviously, the latter does not allow parallel edges or self-loops.

Comment: Thank you! I've already tried DFS solution, I'll try the second one too.. According to you which solution is better in terms of complexity? P.S. Yes I need Pseudograph because it represent a Java source code

Comment: Although marginal, my guess is that the DFS approach is the fastest. It is however hard to answer since I don't know exactly what you want to accomplish. The 2nd approach is conceptually quite clean and can be accomplished in a few lines of code. Ultimately the 2nd approach uses similar iterators as the DFS approach. Is there a reason you were not satisfied with the DFS solution?